# which interactions to explore between sex, age, height to predict weight

Tags: regression, pca, interaction

As a learning exercise I'm running linear regression to predict person's weight from: sex, age, height. here's a few sample lines

```
    Sex Age Height  Weight
860 0   50  162.8   58.1
202 1   34  182.3   89.4
580 0   46  171.5   59.9
762 0   40  167.3   55.9
390 1   50  164.8   69.4
```

having examined the outcome it looks like age is contributing +/- 0.3KG which is very minor. I'm wondering if there is more useful information to be gleaned from age?

1. I've considered adding interaction variables like sex*age or age*height. should I try other interactions?
2. I've considered running PCA. would this just rotate my vectors and achieve nothing, or would it add anything?
3. any other suggestion to try

much obliged

Comment: Have you considered including a quadratic term for age?  Most people gain weight through middle age and then begin to lose weight as they near end of life in older age.  Have you graphed your data?  This might suggest other models that might be more suitable.  I always recommend graphing your data and exploring it before jumping right into modeling.

Witch such a small set of variables, you could consider all possible subsets of variables and interactions.